# Distance between 2 points in a multi-dimensional space

Tags: matrices, geometry

I have 2 elements A and B, each defined by the following features:

- 1 vector (1,2) dimension
- 2 matrices (3,3) dimensions
- 1 matrice (6,7) dimensions

I have no indication on the specifics on the individual matrices (hermitien...).

How can I define the distance between these two elements based on their respectives features ?

I tried to flatten all matrices and transform it in a (1,53) vector but I don't think the approach is the right one.

Comment: If I understand correctly each element has the same kind. Since they both have three components, each one corresponding to one dot in your post, you can use a product metric.

Comment: You're free to define distance however you want. Treating your objects as 53-element vectors works, but depending on your application, you might want to weight the elements differently. It depends on what you're using the distances for.

Comment: I am using the distance for a genetic algorthm approach. When the distance is above a threshold, elements will couple and create a child element. This child element should be at mid-distance of parents. CHild will also have these 3 elements